# TFS / Azure-DevOps - REST API: List of builddefinitions - How to include all properties

Tags: c#, rest, tfs, azure-devops

I'm trying to query the mapping properties for a list of build definitions using the REST API.
I'm using the TFS 2015 with new vNext build definitions.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) you can use the switch **includeAllProperties** to add all properties to the return value.

Here is my code snippet:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

//var data = wc.OpenRead("http://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=2.0");
//var data = wc.OpenRead("http://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions?includeAllProperties=true&api-version=2.0");
//var data = wc.OpenRead("http://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions?includeAllProperties=True&api-version=2.0");
//var data = wc.OpenRead("http://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions?includeAllProperties=TRUE&api-version=2.0");
var data = wc.OpenRead("http://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions?includeAllProperties=0&api-version=2.0");

var response = new StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd();
```

It doesn't seem to matter what I give to the call, I only get the abbreviated answer without properties.

Do I have to call the API differently? Or was this feature not supported in my API version (2.0) yet? Unfortunately I can't find any information about this.

Thank you!

Comment: which property are you trying to get ?

Comment: I'm trying to get the mapping (tfvcMapping).

Comment: did you find the property you are looking for ?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. As @Shamrai Aleksander rightly pointed out, with TFS 2015 you can't read this information within a list. If you fetch the build definitions individually, the information is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is documentation for TFS 2015: [Get a list of build definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/previous-apis/build/definitions?view=tfs-2015#get-a-list-of-build-definitions). It does not contain the includeAllProperties option.